# jQuery: POST data without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

The link is in the footer, The problem is: onclick, the page jumps to the header with a # in the address bar, is there a way to stay in the footer ?

here is my code

```
<a href="#" class="clickIn" id="1" attrIn="Like"><span style="color: #33A13D"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up"></i></span></a>
```

---

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickIn', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var liCount = $('#liCount');
    if($(this).attr('attrIn')=='Like'){
        $.post('page.php',{i:$(this).attr('id'),action:'like'},function(){
        $this.html('done');
        $this.attr('attrIn','');
    });
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event.preventDefault():

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickIn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var liCount = $('#liCount');
    if($(this).attr('attrIn')=='Like'){
        $.post('page.php',{i:$(this).attr('id'),action:'like'},function(){
        $this.html('done');
        $this.attr('attrIn','');
    });
    }
});
```

This cancel default action of browser in specific element. Check reference: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 1):

Yo have to modify your handler to add e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation():

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickIn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $this = $(this);
    var liCount = $('#liCount');
    if($(this).attr('attrIn')=='Like'){
        $.post('page.php',{i:$(this).attr('id'),action:'like'},function(){
        $this.html('done');
        $this.attr('attrIn','');
    });
    }
});
```

This will prevent default action for your link (follow "#" link) and stop the propagation (bubbling) of the click event.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the default behaviour of a triggered event by calling the `preventDefault`method of the event object. I.e.:

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickIn', function(event){
    var $this = $(this);
    var liCount = $('#liCount');

    // Do this:
    event.preventDefault();

    if($(this).attr('attrIn')=='Like'){
        $.post('page.php',{i:$(this).attr('id'),action:'like'},function(){
        $this.html('done');
        $this.attr('attrIn','');
    });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

inside click use

```
event.preventDefault();
```